# Why there is not a deadlock

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class UThread implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (this) {
            System.out.println("this is first");
            synchronized (this) {
                System.out.println("this is second");
            }
        }

    }
}


public class main {
    public static void main(String str[]) {
        UThread uThread = new UThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(uThread);
        t.start();
    }
}
```

When executing code it is printing:

```
this is first
this is second
```

Why there is not a deadlock? if code tries to take a lock on `this` which is already occupied by itself.

Comment: Because it is taken by itself. It only blocks if another thread wants it.

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. Java's `monitorenter`instruction, placed at the opening brace after `synchronized` keyword, intentionally checks if an object is already blocked by the current thread, and if so, increments counter of blockings and lets user's code to continue execution.
The closing brace of the `synchronized` statement denotes `monitorexit` instruction, which decrements the counter of blockings and, if it becomes zero, releases the monitor and allows other threads to enter the `synchronized` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Deadlock, by definition, happens when two or more threads require each others resources to complete their critical section, so the threads wait for the never coming resource indefinitely.

In your case:

- There is only one thread entering the critical section
- There is only one resource in critical section

If there aren't two or more threads awaiting each others critical resource, there cannot be a deadlock.